# Error messages never delivered to error channel after upgrade to 1.1.3 spring integration java dsl

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, dsl

I have used spring integration in our application. Recently we have tried upgrading our project to `spring boot 1.4 release`, which uses `spring java dsl 1.1.3`. In the latest release they have deprecated `messageDriverChannelAdapter` and created a new method with name `messageDriverChannelAdapter`, i.e 'r' fixed.

Integration flow works fine when using `messageDriverChannelAdapter` of java dsl 1.1.1 but it fails in 1.1.3 in a failure case(i.e Exception occur in a flow).

Here is my flow

```
IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter(listenerContainer()).errorChannel(errorChannel())
                        .outputChannel(listenerDirectChannel()))
                .channel(listenerDirectChannel()).transform(new JsonToChangeObjectTransformer())
                .channel(conversionOutChannel()).handle(CHANGED_OBJECT_LISTENER_IMPL, PROCESS_MESSAGE)
                .channel(errorChannel()).handle(FAILED_MESSAGE_HANDLER_IMPL, HANDLE_ERROR).get();
```

I have even tried routing

```
IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(listenerContainer())
                       .errorChannel(errorChannel())
                       .outputChannel(listenerDirectChannel()))
                       .channel(listenerDirectChannel())
                       .transform(new JsonToChangeObjectTransformer())
                       .<Object, Boolean> route(p -> p instanceof ChangedObject,
                        m -> m.channelMapping("true", "conversionOutChannel").channelMapping("false", "errorChannel"))
                         .channel(conversionOutChannel())
                       .handle(CHANGED_OBJECT_LISTENER_IMPL, PROCESS_MESSAGE).channel(errorChannel())
                       .handle(FAILED_MESSAGE_HANDLER_IMPL, HANDLE_ERROR).get();
```

but Still no luck

My observation is message never delivered to error channel(as I have debugged) and it keeps on trying to place message in channel which ultimately causes `stackoverflowerror`

**Exception:**

```
org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:212)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:160)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:292)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:212)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:160)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IntegrarionFlow` definition isn't correct.
When you specify

```
.handle(CHANGED_OBJECT_LISTENER_IMPL, PROCESS_MESSAGE)
.channel(errorChannel())
.handle(FAILED_MESSAGE_HANDLER_IMPL, HANDLE_ERROR)
```

That means an output of the first `.handle()` will be sent to `errorChannel`.
Good result is for error process. Not good...

Not sure that it is what you expect.

Try to separate error flow. For example:

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow jmsMessageDrivenRedeliveryFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(this.jmsConnectionFactory)
                        .errorChannel(IntegrationContextUtils.ERROR_CHANNEL_BEAN_NAME)
                        .destination("jmsMessageDriverRedelivery"))
                .<String, String>transform(p -> {
                    throw new RuntimeException("intentional");
                })
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public CountDownLatch redeliveryLatch() {
        return new CountDownLatch(3);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow errorHandlingFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(IntegrationContextUtils.ERROR_CHANNEL_BEAN_NAME)
                .handle(m -> {
                    MessagingException exception = (MessagingException) m.getPayload();
                    redeliveryLatch().countDown();
                    throw exception;
                })
                .get();
    }
```

Relates to: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues/101